# vue google maps - set max zoom level only for the `fitBounds` call

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

First time using vue google maps. I am trying to manage the max zoom level (6) of a map whenever I add a marker to the map, and I execute `fitBounds`

My code:

```
        setMapBounds(markers = null) {
            if (!markers) {
                markers = this.mapMarkers
            }

            //set bounds of the map
            this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
                if (markers.length) {
                    this.initialZoom = 6;
                    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    for (let m of markers) {
                        bounds.extend(this.getCreatorLocation(m));
                    }

                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                } else {
                    this.initialZoom = 5;
                }
            });
        },
```

How do I force a maximum zoom level (6) during `fitBounds`

Answer (score 0):

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
  if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); 
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
```